# How to write italic capital I / iota?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, italic, capitalization

I'm trying to write I in the following style: [image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Looks like `\mathcal{I}`. The standard LaTeX fonts do not have a special character for the capital iota because it would look like a capital latin-i (I).

Comment: In `unicode-math`, the literal answer to the question you asked is to load `unicode-math` and then use `\mitIota` or `\symit{\Iota}`. Classic LaTeX math fonts use the same codepoint for I and Iota, but it is possible to use the Iota from a legacy 8-bit LGR font if you really wanted to. As @moewe observed, though, that symbol looks more like `\mathcal{I}`.